# I have imported Objective-C files into a Swift project using bridging header, but there is an error "Expected a type"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have copied the `objective-c` files into my `swift` project. I have created a bridging header file in my `swift` project and also imported the objective-c files that are required. But I am facing an issue that "`Expected a type`" at many places in my project.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a missing `@import Foundation;` in the Objective-C header file?

Comment: I tried #import<Foundation/Foundation.h>. Still not working

Comment: In bridging header file Add "#import"myView.h". This myView.h is a class which you are using swift file.

Answer (score 0):

In the bridging header($ProjectName-Bridging-Header) make sure you have imported

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

In addition to this check:

1. The path provided for "Objective-C bridging header" under "Swift
       compiler - general" points the correct location
2. Make sure "Defines Module" under "packaging" is set to "yes"
3. If objective c code uses any custom types or libraries. Ensure it is included as well

Comment: Check if the path provided for   "Objective-C bridging header" under "Swift compiler - general" points the correct location  Also make sure "Defines Module" under "packaging" is set to  "yes"

Comment: Does your objective c code any custom types or libraries. if so all of this must be included in the swift project

Comment: Also check out this link https://jernejcic.com/my-objective-c-return-type-is-giving-expected-a-type-error/

Answer (score 0):

In the Project (Build Setting) Bridging-Header file path sure you set Properly?

`YourProjectName/Bridging-Header-Filename.h`

Comment: Yes I did.."ProjectName/Bridging-Header-file.h"
Here the "Bridging-Header-file.h" is exactly the name of the header file i added to the project.. right?

Comment: @i_am_a_Developer  Remove your  "objective-c"  File and clean your project also remove DerivedData and Delete "Your-Bridging-Header.h" file and recreate Bridging-Header.h file and set-up your code.

First do will BACKUP and try another project.